# export changes in script in oracle (using Toad ?)

Tags: oracle, plsql, merge

I would like beeing able to export all the changes I made in my test DB to the Prod DB with a script (I can't modify data directly in ProdDB).

I would like to have a tool that is generating a merge-script out of a select.
so I could change my data directly in test, and then generate a script, so merge data on prod.

I toad able to do this ? Is there another way to do thins ?

Comment: And I want to ride a [unicorn!](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to generate merge script is to write it yourself during development process.

You add a column to a table? 
Write a line of `alter table foo add (bar number);`, and save it.

You drop one?
`alter table foo drop column bar;`, save.

etc.

Don't rely on TOAD, rely on yourself. You'll be surprised how quickly you learn how things work in Oracle.

Comment: My problem is that I'm manipulating the data (not the structure)... So it is very easy to edit some data directly in the table, to write a merge script for every change, cost more time... So I want a way being able to edit data in the grid, and then to generate a merge script to apply the same changes in the other db

Comment: I've realised, I can export with toad a single table : select the rows wanted, and then export to generate merge script, but it doesn't seems to work with a select on multiple tables ??